# Is there an automatic source code formatter that nicely wraps lines of C/C++?

Tags: c++, formatting, code-formatting

I use astyle to format my code most of the time, and I love it, but one annoyance is that it can't specify at least a "hint" for max line length.  If you have a line of code like:

```
this->mButtonCancel->setLeftClickProc(boost::bind(&FileListDialog::cancelLeftClick, this));
```

I would like a source code formatter to be able to wrap it even moderately intelligently:

```
this->mButtonCancel->setLeftClickProc(
  boost::bind(&FileListDialog::cancelLeftClick, this));
```

...is probably how I would format that line of code.  For long argument lists, I would probably prefer to align on the open parenthesis, but clearly that won't work in this situation.  Either way, astyle doesn't support doing anything with long lines that don't contain multiple statements.  Does anyone know of a tool that does?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GNU Indent has support for breaking long lines.

http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/manual/indent.html#SEC12

Answer (score 5):

I've found **uncrustify** command line tool to be very usable. It has a tremendous number of options, and therefore is a bit hard, but after some practice, it is invaluable.
The homepage is here: 
http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 5):

Astyle 2.03 now support splitting lines based on max-code-length

http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html#_max-code-length

I have tested this, and it splits the line with max-code-length=80, but based on least possible change. I maximizes the amount of code in a line, and hence the breaks aren't always easy to read (but it breaks them)

Comment: I've just tested this, and still get code after column 80. I'm afraid it doesn't count leading spaces into to length.

Comment: These days I have switched to uncrustify almost exclusively.

Answer (score 2):

If you google "Beautify C Code" you will find some nice utilities. I know on *nix there is a binary called bc that does some basic formatting. It is not very customizable, though.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, there is [`clang-format`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) which supports many options configuring line wrapping, e.g. `ColumnLimit: 80` for the width or some of these for controlling when and how to break

```
# alignments at linebreak
AlignAfterOpenBracket: true
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: true
AlignEscapedNewlines: Right
AlignTrailingComments: true

# line break penalties

PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 3
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 2
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 0

AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: No
```